# SharePoint 2010 - 404 Not found Error?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After a migration from 2007, and navigating to the default.aspx page I am getting a 404 Not Found error.

I am unable to determine where this is coming from.  I have looked in the event viewer as well as the ULS logs but cannot isolate the cause of this problem.

Any ideas on how to locate this problem?
thx

Comment: Hey, Did you solved that problem? I'm just wondering because I'm in the same situation myself. I also get the 404 Not Found error from default.aspx after migration from 2007. I have tried to turn off customErrors by making changes to 80\web.config & LAYOUTS\web.config but don't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the system event logs.